# Filter and sort together in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am unable to filter and sort at the same time. I will be getting `products` from axios get call and create a copy of it into `filteredProducts` initially. Then i will be clicking on `sort` and `discount` filter options. Sorting is working fine here but not together with `discount` filter. How can i achieve this together inside `useEffect` ?

```
    const [filteredProducts, setFilteredProducts] = useState([]);

    const handleSort = (sortByValue) => {
        return filteredProducts.sort((a, b) => {
            switch(sortByValue) {
                case 'new' : return parseISO(b.created_at) - parseISO(a.created_at);
                case 'discount' : return b.discount - a.discount;
                case 'price_desc' : return b.price - a.price;
                case 'price_asc' : return a.price - b.price;
                default : return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
            }
        })
    }
    
    const discount = queryParams.get('discount')
    const sortBy = queryParams.get('sort')

    const handleDiscountFilters = (filterResults) => {
        if(discount) {
            return filteredProducts.filter((product) => product.discount > discount)
        } else {
            return products
        }
    }
    
    // Here i want to call the different filter functions first and then call sort function. 
    useEffect(() => {
        let filterResults = [...filteredProducts];
        filterResults = handleDiscountFilters(filterResults)
        filterResults = handleSort(sortBy)
        setFilteredProducts(filterResults);
    }, [filteredProducts, handleDiscountFilters, handleSort, sortBy])
```

Comment: `sort` and `filter` are two different things which should not be clubbed.
First `filter` the data and then `sort` it. But if you `sort` it first and later `filter` you have to `sort` again as it is not guaranteed  the filtered data will be sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code. The first is that you are modifying and setting `filterResults` in the same `useEffect` hook, which means you will have an infinite loop. Every time you call `setFiltereddProducts` the reference value of `filteredProducts` changes, which will cause your `useEffect` to fire again.

Next, similar to how you pass the `filterResults` into `handleDiscountFilters`, you also need to do that for `handleSort`. Right now `handleSort` is reading from the top-level `filteredProducts`, which isn't being impacted by your filters:

```js
  let filterResults = [...filteredProducts];
  filterResults = handleDiscountFilters(filterResults)
  filterResults = handleSort(filterResults, sortBy)
```

But, except for the network call, you really don't need a `useEffect` at all for this:

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

useEffect(async () => {
    const response = await axios.get("someUrl");
    setProducts(response.data);
}, []);

const discount = queryParams.get('discount');
const sortBy = queryParams.get('sort');

const shouldFilterProduct = (product) => {
    if (discount) {
        return product.discount > discount;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};

const sortProduct = (a, b) => {
    switch(sortByValue) {
        case 'new' : return parseISO(b.created_at) - parseISO(a.created_at);
        case 'discount' : return b.discount - a.discount;
        case 'price_desc' : return b.price - a.price;
        case 'price_asc' : return a.price - b.price;
        default : return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
    }
}

const filteredAndSortedProducts = products
    .filter(filterProduct)
    .sort(sortProduct);

return (
    <div>
        {filteredAndSortedProducts.map(product => {
            return <div>{product.name}</div>;
        })}
    </div>
);
```

Comment: This concise code was exactly what i was looking for. This worked !

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the array to the `handleSort` function. Otherwise you sort the initial array, not the filtered one

```
const handleSort = (products, sortByValue) => {
  return products.sort((a, b) => {
    switch (sortByValue) {
      case "new":
        return parseISO(b.created_at) - parseISO(a.created_at);
      case "discount":
        return b.discount - a.discount;
      case "price_desc":
        return b.price - a.price;
      case "price_asc":
        return a.price - b.price;
      default:
        return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
    }
  });
};
```

```
useEffect(() => {
  let filterResults = [...filteredProducts];
  filterResults = handleDiscountFilters(filterResults);
  filterResults = handleSort(filterProducts, sortBy);
  setFilteredProducts(filterResults);
}, [filteredProducts, handleDiscountFilters, handleSort, sortBy]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `handleSort` uses the value declared in the first line of the code, so the value of `filterResults` assigned from the return value of `handleDiscountFilters` is lost, you are always using the unfiltered data.

So, to correct that I would add a parameter to the `handleSort` function, and use that parameter, instead of the const declared in the first line:

```
    const [filteredProducts, setFilteredProducts] = useState([]);

    const handleSort = (values, sortByValue) => {
        return values.sort((a, b) => {
            switch(sortByValue) {
                case 'new' : return parseISO(b.created_at) - parseISO(a.created_at);
                case 'discount' : return b.discount - a.discount;
                case 'price_desc' : return b.price - a.price;
                case 'price_asc' : return a.price - b.price;
                default : return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
            }
        })
    }
    
    const discount = queryParams.get('discount')
    const sortBy = queryParams.get('sort')

    const handleDiscountFilters = (filterResults) => {
        if(discount) {
            return filteredProducts.filter((product) => product.discount > discount)
        } else {
            return products
        }
    }
    
    // Here i want to call the different filter functions first and then call sort function. 
    useEffect(() => {
        let filterResults = [...filteredProducts];
        filterResults = handleDiscountFilters(filterResults)
        filterResults = handleSort(filterResults, sortBy)
        setFilteredProducts(filterResults);
    }, [filteredProducts, handleDiscountFilters, handleSort, sortBy])
```

That's about why the filtering is being ignored, but there are other problems, I think: isn't this being rendered continously in a loop? Because the `handle___` functions are new ones every render, so the useEffect will be invoked also in every render and useEffect is always invoking `setFilteredProducts`, so it will trigger another render, so it never stops rendering. Also, if you set the value after the first render the filtered data would remain filtered (the values filtered out will be lost). I would have a state-associated variable for the source unfiltered data and another derived from it for the filtered data.